# Can I use static class in business logic?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, architecture, static

This might be a repeated question, but lets talk about the stateless application like WEB API, ASP.NET, WCF. All this are state less application. so, can i go with static class's in business logic. Because of static application will work faster.

In our ASP.NET MVC application we have separate project(Library) for Business logic. In that we are using static class. Is that a good way to go with static

Comment: "Because of static application will work faster"  who told you  this ?

Comment: Code isn´t fater because it´s static. In fact it may be faster because it is initialized once and than cached, but this works for non-static classes also.

Comment: It isn't static classes that are faster, it is static methods that are faster than instance methods... But the difference is so little to be negligible. (static methods are faster because they don't have the "hidden" parameter containing the `this` reference... one less parameter->faster to call). static classes are purely synctactic sugar of the C# (they don't exist in the IL intermediate language)

Comment: @xanatos That´s why I won´t even mention this to avoid refactorings for the sake of speed when there is no measurable improvement caused by this refactoring.

Comment: Thanks for all your clear cut explanation. but what is your point on this.
Objects(heap memory) created on demand that means run time. Therefore, by web application design wise, static behave faster.
All the classes loaded and memory created on first application load and this will be reused as long as application runs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a big disadvantage in using static classes: they are VERY difficult to mock for unit testing (and even unit testing is more difficult, depending on the framework used). It is very difficult to mock even static methods. There is no real advantage in static classes, so the answer is: don't use static classes for business logic. Don't use static methods for business methods.

Comment: i am agree with you ;)

Answer (score 0):

**No**,
Because when you use the static class, that is mean you don't want to create an instance of the class and it is a very rear case on business logic.

Answer (score 0):

Its not good for several reasons:

1. Static class cannot be instantiated and save state that is not shared, therefor you basically killing the OOD principle.
2. Because static can't save state and be instantiated, so usually the signatures of the methods will be more complicated and the code will be more messy.
3. Its easier to get wrong when there is much static code and make code replication.
4. When you writing often static code its harder to keep project boundaries right.

In short, try to avoid static code unless it shouts "static" like extension methods and such. Clean Code and Solid principles can give you much deeper understanding why you should avoid it.